# "ms sql" means microsoft SQL Server or MS Access

Tags: mssql-jdbc

In netbeans, during new database connection for "ms-sql", I get:

> Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=bombermario using com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver (The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. 
>   Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.

Comment: Well, the error messages **says** that it's **SQL Server** - no ?

Comment: ms-sql  and Sql server are same or not @marc_s

Comment: ***YES*** The product is **officially** called **SQL Server**, but a lot of programmer refer to is as "MSSQL", or "ms sql" or whatever

Comment: to connect ms sql in netbeans it is possible @marc_s

Comment: i install  microsoft sql server 2005 driver in netbeans then what i do

Answer (score 1):

MS-SQL means SQL server, not MS Access.

Comment: ms sql means sql server